# Firebase authentication shows duplicate e-mail addresses with the same provider (Google)

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication

I have an angular app running with firebase and Google authentication only (no other providers are configured)

On the firebase console/dashboard @ authentication -> users i see duplicate e-mail addresses with the same provider (Google) and different UIDS. How can i prevent this behavior? (see screenshot)

[image: duplicate e-mail addresses]

Comment: Please share a screenshot as well if possible. This sounds strange and must be addressed.

Comment: i have included a screenshot